# ServletContext.addServlet()がundefined

Tags: java, spring

SpringMVCアプリケーションの設定を、設定クラスから行おうとしたところ、
ServletContext.addServlet()がないというエラーが発生しました。

調べてもいまいち原因がよくわからず、困っています。
ご教授お願いします。

```
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;

import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

public class ApplicationInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer{

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {
        XmlWebApplicationContext appContext = new XmlWebApplicationContext();
        appContext.setConfigLocation("/WEB-INF/spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml");
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = container.addServlet("spring-dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(appContext)); // ここ
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");
    }
}
```

ServletAPI 2.5
spring一式 4.2.0
java 8
Eclipse Mars
tomcat 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ServletContextにaddServletメソッドが追加されたのはServlet3.0からになります。
ですので、利用されているServlet2.5ではメソッドが存在しません。

ただし、Tomcat8はServlet3.1のはずです。
Tomcatとは別のAervletAPIをパスに通しているのであれば、
TomcatのServletAPIと同じバージョンをパスに通すことをお勧めします。